# OkHttpClient - Sending a get request with Bearer token fails due to auth

Tags: java, authorization, okhttp, bearer-token

I'm using OkHttpClient in a Java service and I'm trying to send a `get` request with an `Authorization` header.

For some reason, the below *fails* with response code `401` as if the token isn't sent within the headers.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder();
        .url(url)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        .build();

var response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

I also tried out using the `headers` builder param and passing a `Headers` object containing `Authorization` `Bearer some-token`, and also tried with `addHeader("Authorization", token)` but same happens.

OkHttpClient version: 4.9.2

What's wrong with the above code? Is OkHttpClient stripping off the Authorization header for some reason?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @androidneil I personally opted for a different http client, because after inspecting the okhttpclient source code, it strips the authorization headers for some weird security reasons.